# Finding the kernel in which the data will have the highest ratio of leading eigenvalue to trace

Tags: kernel

I have a method which works well with the data where a ratio of a leading eigenvalue or of first few leading eigenvalues to trace is high. Is it possible to find a kernel transformation which is optimized in such a way (across possible values of hyperparameters and functional forms) that in the kernel space such ratio is at the highest possible value (and higher than in the original feature space)? Thank you.

Comment: Eigenvalue/trace of which matrix? The Gram (kernel) matrix?

Comment: Yes, the Gram matrix of the space created by this kernel.

Comment: As this is a positive definite symmetric matrix, then the trace is the sum of all eigenvalues. So you want a feature space were few dimensions are long and the others are small, i.e. a dimension that holds most variance

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right. So how would you recommend to address this problem - which family of kernels would you select?